# Negative values coming on datetime difference in apex why?

Tags: apex

Hi have requirement to show real time TAT i have added piece of code to get difference between to datetimes based on business hours. Code is working as expected for latest data for old data like 3 months back dack records showing negative values.

```
 Datetime targetTime = System.now(); 
 Long milliseconds = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, lead[0].CreatedDate , targetTime);
 remainingHours = milliseconds.intValue();
 system.debug('test'+remainingHours);

output is test==>-1928315076
```

Please help me to solve this issue. why negative values coming in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with data types in Apex. The maximum value of a `Long` is 2<sup>63</sup>-1 (roughly 10,000,000,000,000,000,000), whereas the maximum value of an `Integer` is 2,147,483,647.

If you convert a `Long` that exceeds the maximum value of an `Integer`, the value "overflows" and continues counting from the start of the range.

The minimum value for an `Integer` is -2,147,483,648, so for example, if you take 2,147,483,648 (one more than the maximum) and convert it to an `Integer`, you'd get -2,147,483,648.

Check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) for a detailed explanation on Integer overflow.